# Windows-to-Linux-migration

Tags: software-installation, playonlinux, migration

I am new to Linux, I have been using Windows since I was 9, I have heard things about Linux and I ***truly*** enjoy what I have seen so far, although, I came from a Windows OS and ***I don't want to buy new programs*** and games just to be able to use them, is there a way I can use my games and programs on Linux **without a virtual machine**, please ***note:*** I want to migrate completely to Linux and this is my only problem I have to resolve before completely moving, if you answer, this might sound daft, but please explain as if you are explaining to a mellon, thanks???

Comment: steam has proton which lets you play windows games in linux there is wine which proton is based on and there is lutris for a gui and install scripts for wine here is lutris site https://lutris.net/ that all being said you should ask about specific programs you want or need as there is likely a linux alternative if there is no support for the program in question

Comment: also ask any questions you have as I am a daily linux mint user and the only games I can't get running at this point are the ones with anti cheat systems like battleye

Comment: For programs/games you must have, a google search with name and Ubuntu or Linux will give you an idea if it works well.  You will have to decide if you must have exact program or can use a slightly different program in ubuntu.  An example would be photoshop and gimp.

Comment: If you want to consider virtual options later on, we can help with that, too. The first thing we would need to check is if your CPU and motherboard will support virtualization, which means we need to know the make and model of your PC to tell you. Perhaps you've already done so, but if not, just ask.

Comment: I would either dual boot for gaming or ... even though you state not wanting to ... to use virtualization: windows IN Ubuntu if you have machine for it.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Unlike Windows, the vast majority of Linux software is free so you don't have to buy new programs. As others have said there are usually Linux alternatives that cover almost everything imaginable. If you are talking about installing Windows programs under Linux visit the called duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

Although you can migrate many Steam games, and some other games, not all games or apps will migrate.

The sole solution without virtualization is [Dual-Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi); [installing Ubuntu](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/how-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot.html) on the [same drive](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/) which now boots Windows. Once installed, you will be offered the [choice of which operating system to boot](https://www.itzgeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Install-Ubuntu-18.04-Alongside-With-Windows-10-Boot-Ubuntu-18.04.png), every time you boot. If you make no choice before it times out, the top OS on the list boots; you can edit that list if you want to change the order of choice.